# UICollectionViewDelegate not firing on UICollectionView subclass with custom UICollectionViewCell and NSObject controller

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, xib, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

I have subclassed `UICollectionView` and assigned its delegate and datasource to an NSObject class. I use a custom `UICollectionViewCell`with a .xib to construct the collection view's cells. The project can be found here:
https://github.com/JeffModMed/CustomUICollectionView

As you'll see, the datasource methods are working fine, but `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and `shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath` are not called when the user taps on a cell, which leads me to believe there's something with `UICollectionViewDelegate`. The only other possible problem area I can think of is that there's something wrong with how I'm using the custom `UICollectionViewCell` class or registering its .xib file.

Note: Please don't answer suggesting that I use `UICollectionViewController` as an alternative: the code has to be done this way for incorporation with a larger project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow. Great puzzle. I've been pulling this apart for 20 minutes and I can't figure out why your delegate functions aren't getting called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the MMFilterTagCollectionViewCell.xib, select the cell and enable the **User Interaction Enabled** option.

In the MMFilterTagCollectionView.m file, comment out this line:

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

Comment: You are literally my hero.